# Is Microsoft Bot Framework in Teams free with my own endpoint?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, botframework, azure-bot-service

I would like to understand how payments work as far as Microsoft Bot Framework is concerned.
This is my scenario: In Visual Studio Code I wrote an bot app using Microsoft Teams Toolkit to use it as a chatbot in Microsoft Teams. My company has an Azure Active Directory subscription, so my bot app appeared there. This app communicates with an endpoint which is NOT hosted on Azure.

So my question is - will it generate any extra costs? Should I worry about this 10000 messages per month limit?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bot-services/

As I understand I'm not using Azure Bot Services as I host my endpoint and I'm taking care of the logic, am I right?

My endpoint is written in .Net Core using Bot Framework SDK. So I use their classes and also MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword is also sent to the endpoint (obligatory to use with Teams).

Thanks for clearing it for me.

Comment: Questions about product or service pricing are off topic as explained in [Are questions on prices or support of developer services on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274576), [Questions about licensing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a licensing or pricing question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see in the link that the limit only applies to premium channels. Your Teams bot should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, now I noticed that there is a description about what a channel is :)